# How to show only one option of the many options to each participant on Qualtrics using Piped Text?

Tags: qualtrics

Background:

1. 193 emails. Each email is one sentence.
2. mTurk participants see the question "the next day you receive this email (inserted one email out of 193 emails)" then asked to rate the email. The question is Descriptive Text. The rating is made into a separate multi-choice question.

What I want to do:

Each participant will see only one email out of the 193 emails, randomly.

What I tried to do:

Using Piped Text to pipe 193 emails into Descriptive Text. I tried to input the 193 emails into Loop & Merge, then pipe Loop & Merge into Descriptive Text. None of the emails was shown when I previewed the block.

My sense now is that I should use embedded data, but I can't figure out a way to input the 193 emails into an embedded data field.

My question:

How to achieve what I want to do? I'm also open to using tools other than Piped Text. I just can't figure out a way to do this on Qualtrics. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your survey flow, add a randomizer then under the randomizer add 193 embedded data blocks.  Inside each embedded data block assign one of the 193 emails to the embedded data variable.

```
email_pipe = Email 1
email_pipe = Email 2
email_pipe = Email 3
etc.
```

Set the randomizer to present 1 of the 193 elements and check Evenly Present.

If you find it cumbersome to do in the survey flow, you could do a multiple choice question with 193 choices and use Advanced Randomization to randomly display 1 of the 193 choices, evenly presented. Then hide the question with JavaScript and pipe the displayed choices into your question.

Comment: Thank you very much! Both ways work amazingly and I didn't know that I could code  Javascript in Qualtrics until now! Great help!